AWS Connect - play recording to the agent and contact while call is active. Or, inject a text to speech string into the active call
I am working with AWS Connect using a custom UI with the connect streams api. Short version, when my agent is on a call with an inbound caller, I want to be able to play a recording or inject a text to speech voice into the live call. We have an exact compliance statement that we do not want our agents to read but rather initiate it playing on the call that is being recorded.
Details.
React site including the aws-connect-streams js. Where agent logs into our connect instance. Everything is currently working.

Pinpoint starts an outbound dialing journey routing connected calls to AWS Connect instance.
Connected call routes to an inbound queue where the flow starts logging, starts call recording, uses lambda to lookup some custom caller info from our database and the flow ends by dropping the caller in a queue.
Agents are logged into this queue through a custom ui that has the aws connect workspace embedded.
Once the agent and caller are connected later on in the call, we need to somehow play the agent and caller a recording or specific text be read by text to speech and played in the call.

My UI knows when the recordings should be played so I can use connect-streams-api from the client or I can talk to my api server and execute anything in the entire AWS SDK. I cannot find any way in connect-streams docs or in aws sdk for Connect docs that enables any way to inject audio or text2speech into a live call. The flow the queue goes through is too early and as far as I understand a flow once the agent is connected the flow is over.
What I have attempted so far:
I made a new queue with a flow that plays a prompt.
I claimed a new DID number and pointed it to that ^ new queue that plays recording.
Using the streams api while the agent and caller are talking I add a new connection to their call pointed to the new queue phone number and immediately conference the agent the caller and the connected queue that plays the prompt (and then terminates the call).
This works 50% of the time, the call always connects and conferences with the agent and caller but sometimes it is just 10 seconds of silence like the queue is playing the recording but it is not coming through on the conferenced call (the agent and external caller cannot here the recording).
After 10 seconds of silence (the length of the recording) the conferenced call disconnects which is by design but the recording audio is not always audible. This happens with audio files or text to speech in the Play Prompt flow block attached to the queue.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, this is my last hurdle.

The silence happens both with text to speech and audio as well?

Disclaimer: I haven’t implemented this myself, but I’m familiar with the system. If you’re looking for a definitive solution, feel free to ignore this. Just trying to help.
Since silence occurs half of the times, I suspect the issue may be a result of lag or synchronization problem.
Try to add a buffer, you can achieve it by adding a short quiet buffer at the beginning of the prompt, start playing the prompt and then connect to the call. 
This way, you give the system enough time to load the audio before trying to play it. There might be some better ideas in this direction.
Another, more “clean” option would be to utilize a new and specific IVR Queue, which is solely played the prompt you want.
At the point you want you transfer both caller and agent to the queue, let the audio play and the message ends, the system transfers the call back. 
I can think of two ways to do so: 
The first is to trigger a separate flow which will wait for the call to begin (plus margin you want) and then will move the call to the IVR queue.
The second is connecting to the call via API and using the API to transfer the call at the moment you want.
Another option will be to utilize lambda function that will perform the transfer base on some condition but seems to me that adding lambda on top of everything will make the system much more complex than needed.

Hello Avifen, thanks a lot for the input.
The only way I have been able to get anything close to what I want is to do exactly what you suggested. I have 3 DID numbers, each directed to a queue that plays the recording and disconnects.
While agent and customer are on call I AM able to conference them both into each DID # which leads to each new queue which plays the recording. This is the instance where the recording is playing but not audible some of the time. I have 2 seconds of silence at start of each recording, any thoughts as to why sometimes it can be heard?

Can you try instead of a two sec silent at same record, two records, one is silent one is the audio?

Yeah that is a good idea. I will try that and confirm, thanks a lot!

sure, let me know

2 recordings did not fix anything. I also re-sampled the audio down to 8000 k sample rate, still no good. I did notice that it becomes very reliable if I conference in the same number twice (on top of each other)... very odd. thanks for you help.

@NickLicata - would you be able to share how did you manage to send the audio when call is active to the caller.

I got this to work by using a quick connect that sends to a queue and that queue has a play prompt block and then resume block. Let me know if you need more detail and I will send an export of my flow.
